# Why OSMF doesn't have an org.osmf.net.netstream class?

Tags: actionscript, netstream, osmf

I wish I could grab some information from the codec (freeze, error frames, decoding errors for example), and hence I imagine this is performed in the NetStream class and I could have it send more info than the SRTT, bitrate & co.

So, I'm asking ! Is a Netstream class source code available in OSMF ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can try many of the other net classes in org.osmf.net. that do exactly what you want.
For instance, to capture net connection and status events, you can check out the org.osmf.net.Netloader class.
And yes, the source code is available and is also compilable ;-)